# mocha test failed with unknown option -r

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

If I run TCs as  "mocha -r .\test-scripts\mocha-setup.js .\test\test-ms.spec.js --exit ", I can run the TCs, but if I run as "mocha -r .\test-scripts\mocha-setup.js --exit ".\test\test-ms.spec.js, I get unknown option -r . Any idea why I get different behavior depends on where I pass --exit ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you provide args, `--exit` is in the middle of the values for `-r` where its a list of modules(files) to require. The below should work.

```
mocha -r .\test-scripts\mocha-setup.js .\test\test-ms.spec.js --exit
```